# "Is-a" relationship in Solr Synoyms

Tags: solr, synonym

I have two texts:

Text-1

> Our new Android Smartphone

Text-2

> Our new iPhone Smartphone

I would like to tell Solr that "android" **is a** "smartphone".

Expected results:

If the user searches for "Android" only the first text should be found.

If the user searches for "Smartphone" both texts should be found.

If I use "equal synonyms" ([SolrSynonymParser](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_2_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SolrSynonymParser.html)) (during indexing), then the term "Smartphone" would get expanded to "Smartphone, Android, iPhone" in both texts.

Comment: A synonym entry as `android => android, smartphone` as an index time synonym would handle that, wouldn't it? If the user searches for "android", a hit would be made, but only to the document mentioning android. If the user searches smartphone, both would match (as the synonym has expanded `android` to `android` and `smartphone` (in your example you'd get the result regardless of synonyms since both contain the text `smartphone`)

Comment: There might be more to this question, but on the surface, indexing your text in a  `text_general` field will give you the expected results (a search for "android" will return one doc whereas a search for "smartphone" will give you both documents) -- i.e. you wouldn't need to rely on synonyms for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the comment of MatsLindh, to add an unidirectional synonym like: "android=>android,smartphone", you should also consider to add the Synonym Filter only at index time and not both at index and query time

For example:

```
<analyzer type="index"> 
   ...
   <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
   ... 
</analyzer>
```

This way, both "android" and "smartphone" will be indexed for any occurrence of "android"